# How to validate input field form so its a website address

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

So I have a predicament. A client is using an online form maker so I have no access to the code. They want one of the field to be a website field but it can only be submitted if it shows an actual website domain. I figured the easiest way would be to only allow the form submission if the input includes a . (all domains will have one of these somewhere).

I can add JS so if there is a workaround using that please advise!

I understand JS but can struggle with certain areas (like this one)!

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: you need to use regex

Comment: only checking for a '.' is very unrestrictive. you should add some other conditions (no spaces, no special characters, min./max. length of characters etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an input element with type `url` check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/url